# UICollectionView adding image and button

Tags: xcode, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I used UICollectionView for displaying the images from CameraRoll, it is working fine, now I want to add the Camera button in the collectionview cell. I had written the code like this, button is not getting displayed.

```
- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
UICollectionViewCell *cell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"collectionCell" forIndexPath:indexPath];

[self.cameraRoll thumbAtIndex:indexPath.row completionHandler:^(UIImage *thumb) {
    UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:thumb];
    imageView.frame = CGRectMake(0,0,cell.frame.size.width, cell.frame.size.height);
    imageView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFill;
    [cell.contentView addSubview:imageView];

    //Now Create Button
    UIImage* img = [UIImage imageNamed:@"btn_take_pic"];
    UIImageView *btnImage = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:img];
    btnImage.frame = CGRectMake(0,0, 50,50);
    btnImage.frame = CGRectMake(0,0,cell.frame.size.width, cell.frame.size.height);
    btnImage.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFill;
    //End of create button

    [cell.contentView addSubview:btnImage];//Add Button to the cell


}];

return cell;
}
```

Comment: You are not creating any button in cell. are you ...???

Comment: First I want to show btn_take_pic image in the cell, after that I want to show all the cameraroll images...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the solution for the issue I mentioned above, I think it might be helpful for others, so positing the code here

```
- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
   UICollectionViewCell *cell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"collectionCell" forIndexPath:indexPath];
   if(indexPath.row>0)
    [self.cameraRoll thumbAtIndex:(indexPath.row-1) completionHandler:^(UIImage *thumb) {
    UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:thumb];
    imageView.frame = CGRectMake(0,0,cell.frame.size.width, cell.frame.size.height);
    imageView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFill;
    [cell.contentView addSubview:imageView];
}];
else{
    UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"btn_take_pic.png"]];
    imageView.frame = CGRectMake(0,0,cell.frame.size.width, cell.frame.size.height);
    imageView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFill;
    [cell.contentView addSubview:imageView];
}
return cell;
}
```

Comment: Hi, i have a question for You. What is that -> self.cameraRoll ? I am beginner, and unfortunately i can't catch that. Please, help me ;) –

Answer (score 2):

Create Button like this

```
- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
UICollectionViewCell *cell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"collectionCell" forIndexPath:indexPath];

//Add your image showing code here

//Now Create Button in cell

    CGRect btnRect = CGRectMake(0, 0 , 30 , 30);
    UIButton *cellBtn = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:btnRect];
    [cellBtn setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"img.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [cellBtn setTitle:@"Text to Show" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [cell.contentView addSubview:cellBtn];        

    [[cell cellBtn] addTarget:self action:@selector(CellBtnTapped:event:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

return cell;
}
```

method for button tap

```
-(void)CellBtnTapped:(id)sender event:(id)event
{
// perform your action here that you want to do on button tap
}
```

But It is good that you should make a separate class for your CollectionViewCell and add all objects there, that you want to take in your collectionView cell.

Comment: Thanks Zubair this is giving some idea.Actually button should come in separate cell.... in your solution button is displayed over an image.

Comment: @ M Zubair Shamshad add target is showing error     [[cell cellBtn] no visible interface found

Comment: @UmaMadhavi `[cellBtn addTarget:self action:@selector(performBidAction) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];` you can use it like too.

Comment: @ M Zubair Shamshad  That is working fine . I am passing array of buttons in collection view cell so ,if i click on one button ,it should change background color(selected only).

Comment: @UmaMadhavi assign tags to your buttons and when you have to change the background color of specific button compare the tags

Comment: @MZubairShamshad I have taken one button in collectionviewcell and assigned tag. Individually should i add tag